# SQL Server Data Archive Solution

Tags: sql-server, archive, solution

I'm looking for a solution to archive data that exists in my database. My database is SQL Server 2008 and have approximately 250 tables. I search web and find the below link :
http://www.dbazine.com/sql/sql-articles/charran13/

but this solution is not clear

I don't know that is there a direct way for doing this in sql server. please give me a solution.

Comment: Taking backups is a common archival strategy!

Comment: Yes I know but getting full backup don't resolve my requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution that you choose to rollout will be dependent on your reasons for implementing data archival.

For example you will need to consider:

1. **What data is to be archived?**

   For example all data or data older
   than a    certain date?

   This has implications for the most
   suitable archive techniques to be
   used, i.e. whether a full database
   backup could suffice or perhaps a
   purpose built archiving process
   using [SQL Server Integration
   Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) may be more suitable.
2. **How accessible does the archived data need to be?**

   Does the archived data need to be
   immediately available, perhaps on
   slower SATA storage or perhaps a
   period of several days to acquire
   access to the data is acceptable?
   Perhaps if the restore time is quite
   liberal then a FULL database backup,
   taken at regular intervals, say once
   a month could suffice. If on the
   other hand the data needs to be very
   much on hand then a solution.
3. **What are the security implications required by the data?**

   For example, should backups be
   encrypted or if data is being stored
   offsite is there adequate physical
   security in place?

Perhaps if you could provide some more details as to your reasons for wishing to archive your data and also how much of your data you wish to archive, then we may be able to provide more specific guidance.

Comment: Hi John

I have a large application with 12 subsystems like accounting system, asset management system, inventory management system, training management system, ....
usually data saved in one year is not needed in next years except for occasional cases.It means that every one year we must archive data.
With this solution we want to maximize application performance.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe replication be a solution for you.