# what's a good way to synchronize a sql server 2008 database from a 2005 database automatically?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Ok, the scenario is... two servers, on completely different parts of the internet.

The sql 2008 database just needs to get data updates and schema changes.  It doesn't need to send anything to the 2005 database.  Basically just suck data and schema as efficiently as possible automatically as a scheduled task.

The database is quite huge.... but the changes per day are probablly around 20/30 megabytes of data/

I can't run any of the inbuilt replication on the 2005 database.

I've had a wee look at the Sync Framework, I think that might do what I want, but seems a bit painful and requires a bit of work to get going.   I'm wondering if there is tooling out there to make this easier?

or??  not quite sure what my options are.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't run any of the inbuilt
>   replication on the 2005 database.

Any reason for this restriction? Replication is *the* way to solve your problem. W/o a replication infrastructure you simply won't be able to detect data changes, nor schema changes. There are only two ways to detect the changes: either via triggers and tracking tables (and that is Merge Replication) or via the database log (and that is Transactional Replication).

Sync Framework itself, if it would be used, would require either Change Tracking or Change Data Capture. But these are 2008 specific technologies and they're really nothing else but replication in disguise (they use the very same infrastructure used by Merge and respectively Transactional Replication).

Even if you want to roll your own, you'll find out quickly that shipping the changes over is the trivial part, eg. using [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166071.aspx) for reliable delivery semantics. But the Real hard problem is detecting the changes, and that is *hard*. Diff-ing a 'quite huge' database over the internet to detect changes is just not going to work. So relying on the built-in infrastructure to detect changes, namely the two forms of Replication, is just the obvious solution.

Comment: well, not 100% on this restriction, but as far as I can tell, it will modify the database to add unique identifiers to all the tables.  This will be a massive overhead. Most of the bulk of the data is in 1 table (though other tables change also).   adding another column to this table would be expensive.  The one thing about most of the tables is they are really are immutable.... no data gets changed and no data gets deleted, data only gets added.

Comment: Transactional Replication doesn't add anything to the articles being replicated.

Answer (score 1):

Could you automate RedGate's SQL Compare and/or SQL Data Compare?  http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm  ... you could at least try that out with the 14-day trial and see if it is worth the investment.  Much cheaper than tooling it yourself, IMHO.

Comment: Why not?  The Pro version of both tools support command-line... you don't have to use the UI permanently.

Comment: I've also added a selection of comparable tools in this article (which was aimed at avoiding the issues involved with writing your own solution to a problem that someone else has already solved, it just happens to focus on this particular problem):

http://www.onetooneinteractive.com/otocorporate-posts/2009/06/01/the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/?showin=otolabs

Answer (score 1):

maybe these questions help you:

[Microsoft Sync Framework Or Replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607103/microsoft-sync-framework-or-replication)

[SQL Server Data Archive Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584783/sql-server-data-archive-solution)

[Is there a way to replicate some data not all data in db by sql server replication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309297/is-there-a-way-to-replicate-some-data-not-all-data-in-db-by-sql-server-replicatio)

you can make an application that generate a script from your changed data in your favorite period and then run this script in your target server.

Comment: seen those, and no.... not really.  Well, the first one does.... I could use that.  But seems a bit more involved than I was originally wanting.